# How to hide a HDD from device manager?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, drivers, device-manager

I somehow managed to "hide" one of my SATA HDDs from XP's device manager. No yellow signs or anything and it does not work. BIOS can still see it however. On Linux, its partitions still work as expected.

I don't exactly know what did I to achieve this.

Can you help me find out what can hide a HDD from device manager?

It is not listed in diskpart either.

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at all connected drives with [diskpart](http://www.computerhope.com/diskpart.htm) and seeing if it's recognized there.

Comment: Did you placed the harddrive in a RAID controller configuration? If so, windows will see the RAID controller instead of the actual harddrive's attached to it. Linux works differently and probably therefor can still see the harddrive.

Comment: @root did that, it is unlisted. Note that the drive is missing from *the device manager*, so I'd expect it's highly unlikely that disk management tools would show it. Good tip nevertheless!

Comment: @LPChip No I didn't. But wasn't aware of that. I have one appropriate device in SCSI and RAID controllers, which controls 2x SATA3 connectors; the motherboard has 4x more SATA2. I checked devices by connection. I see the SATA3 controller has one of the *other* HDDs listed. One that I do see as a disk as well. So still cannot see the HDD I'm looking for. Need to learn how do I manage the RAID configuration. (BTW I didn't touch the BIOS nor the hardware.) Then I could see whether it has my HDD.

Comment: @naxa when you boot your computer, you'll get a brief moment where it says `press CTRL-J to accees the RAID controller setup` (or whatever key combination it uses. If you have more raid controllers, you'll have more setups you can enter. They'll all are listed there. Note that if you set your harddrive controller not as RAID, the setup will not be enabled. this is a BIOS setting.

Comment: @LPChip thanks! in BIOS I have two RAID controllers, both in IDE mode. Onboard having 4x slot and another chip doing 2x. The other chip has my HDD in BIOS. Still can't see in XP. However I had a strange experience. I was moving the house while on and something just spin up, and in device manager for a brief period of time the missing HDD model appeared. Then it disappeared again. I thought about contact issues but Linux can always use it. I thought, is there a power configuration somewhere which can cause something like this? Still troubling that mechanical moving had this effect.

Comment: If you have a brief moment of contact like this, first thing I'd do is power down the computer, open it, unplug all cables and reseat them in the exact same position (thus unplug one cable, plug back in, next cable, etc...)

Comment: @LPChip okay thanks! Windows froze few minutes later anyway. :) I go on re-plugging now. No flush damage happened btw. However I'd like to add I'm not certain which device made the contact problem. It could have been that a "visible" HDD gone off and on, so XP re-enumerated the devices and that's where I saw my "hidden" HDD? Just an alternate theory.